# Fastest method to combine two tables SQL on Hive/impala

Tags: sql

I need to Know, in terms of processing speed, which is the best and Fastest way to combine two tables between, Full OUTER JOIN, UNION ALL + aggregation, CROSS JOIN, etc...

Consider -> **Table1** : Fields (Id, C1) ***
**Table2** : Fields (Id, C2)

The result must be Table3 : (Id, C1, C2), with all records on both tables, without duplicated Id's.

So,

1. for common Id's on both tables will have : (**Id**, C1, C2)
2. for unique Id's on Table1 will have : (**Id**, C1, NULL)
3. for unique Id's on Table2 will have : (**Id**, NULL, C2)

My best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full outer join will be your best way to go.

A [union all](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-full-outer-join-and-union-in-SQL) + aggregation will take additional steps since you essentially concatenate both datasets then do some additional cleaning.

[CROSS JOIN](https://365datascience.com/question/cross-join-vs-full-outer-join/) won't get what you're looking for - it just takes the cartesian product, which will give you all possible combinations of all rows.